# LINQ in C# to create and map new Unique Id's

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have been a data and bi developer. I am asked to learn C# and use LINQ to create ETL jobs. I have the below scenario, where I need some help & guidance.

- Raw Data Table - Transactions_Raw

  ```
  Columns:  
  Trade_Id | InstrumentId | AccountId | Trade_Amount | Trade Type | Trade Date
  ```
- Table 1 - Instrument (Unique Instrument)

  ```
  Columns:
  Id | IdSource | InstrumentType | Active
  ```
- Table 2 - Account (Unique Accounts)

  ```
  Columns:
  Id | IdSource | AccountType | Active
  ```
- Table 3 - Resolution (Unique Instrument & Account combination based on incoming Fact Data)

  ```
  Columns:
  Id | InstrumentId | AccountId | Resolution Start Date | Active
  ```
- Final Fact Table - Transactions

  ```
  Columns:
  ResolutionId | Trade Date | Trade Type | Trade Type
  ```

Based on the records coming from Raw Table (Transactions_Raw).

- If the `InstrumentId` is not present in Instrument table then create an entry
- If the `Accountd` is not present in Account table then create an entry
- Create a unique `ResolutionId` based on the Combination of `InstrumentId+ Accountd`
- Move the transaction to Fact table based on `ResolutionId`, hiding `Instrument&Account`

If the combination of `InstrumentId+Accountd` already exists in the Resolution table, then just move the Transaction data from Raw to Fact based on the `ResolutionId`.

I hope that the explanation is clear.

Comment: What is your question? What have you tried?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, you would recommend to read this [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and modify your question in order to help users to understand your problem.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This is not a free code writing service. What did you try so far? Please [edit] your question and post your code as a [mcve]! What happened when you ran it? What did you expect to happen instead? What specifically are you having problems with?

Comment: The below code is what I am trying to use to find the new entity pair that came from raw data to insert into Investment table
I am getting an error using the "join" keyword
var result = (from gfsAum in context.GfsPositions
join Inv in context.Investments 
on new { gfsAum.Isin, gfsAum.Register_ID } equals new { Inv.InstrumentId ,  Inv.FinAcctId}  into pair
from InvestmentDao in pair.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new { gfsAum.Isin, gfsAum.Register_ID }).ToList();
foreach (var item in result)
{
entityPairs.Add(new Tuple<GfsPositionDao, InvestmentDao>(item.Isin, item.Register_ID));
}

Comment: Error: the type of one of the expression in the join in incorrect.